# Axios Post returning no data after 200 response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, api, redux, axios

I am playing around with React (I'm a newbie) and trying to make a post request to my rails API (on localhost atm). I wrote the post function to also console.log my response and I consistently get a 200 response, confirming that the object has been successfully created in my API. However, I want to look through my http response to confirm that the correct parameters have been passed through and it seems that there is no body. Not sure if I am missing in my post request or if I am updating my state incorrectly after I make the post request.

My React Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import update from 'immutability-helper'
import BusinessForm from './businessForm'

const API = 'http://localhost:3001/api/v1/businesses/'

class NewBusinesses extends Component {   




 state = {
    businesses: [],
    editID: null


    }
  check = () => {
    console.log(this.state.businesses)
  }
  addNew = () => {
    axios.post(
      API,
        {
          business:
          { name: 'NEW BUSINESS',
            address: '',
            city: '',
            zip: '',
            wifi: '',
            phone: '',
            bathroom: ''
           }
        }
    )
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
        const businesses = update(this.state.businesses, {
          $splice: [[0,0,response.data]]
        })
        this.setState({businesses: businesses,
        editID: response.data.id})
        })
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

Console after I onClick the function (console.log(response))

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

config:{adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data:""
headers:
{content-type: "text/html", cache-control: "no-cache"}
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status:200
statusText:"OK"
__proto__:Object
```

Comment: Does the rails controller in your API return data after a post request is sent to it?

Comment: @aaron.v thanks for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! This issue was on the API side not due to anything I did in my React app. I had to add the line

```
render json:@business
```

to my create method in my Rails API

Comment: not sure if this applies to you but you also may need to do this for post requests.

```axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = yourCSRFTokenHere;
   axios.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json';
```

Comment: ^^ good shout Brandon. It's important to have accept headers correct if you use `respond_to` with formats for js. Without it, Rails will respond with default `html` format.